# Calculating 95% confidence intervals for Cramér's V?

Tags: confidence-interval, spss, effect-size, reporting, cramers-v

I'd like some advice an analysis I calculated an effect size for using Cramér's V in SPSS, which I'd like to report along with its upper and lower 95% CIs. Would someone be able give me some guidance on how to find these? I'd be very grateful.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrapping seems to be the most common. Apparently a sampling distribution and closed-form CI has been proposed, but I've not seen that implemented outside of [this](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1348226-how-to-display-confidence-intervals-around-kramer-s-v) discussion (so you may want to proceed with caution).

Comment: The {confintr} package in R can find CIs both via Bootstrapping and via numeric inversion of the non-central F distribution function. But no idea how to do it in SPSS... `confintr::ci_cramersv()`.